# Change the name of the "Add" button in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

As we known, there is an "Add" button in each model in django admin site. How can I change the name of it into like "Add Student" to make it customerized.

I have found the add button in the template

```
{% if has_add_permission %}
    {% url cl.opts|admin_urlname:'add' as add_url %}

    <el-button size="small" type="primary" icon="el-icon-plus" data-name="add_item"
               url="{% add_preserved_filters add_url is_popup to_field %}">
        {% trans 'Add' %}
    </el-button>
{% endif %}
```

I change the "{% trans 'Add' %}" and the button's name can be changed, but all the models page Add button are changed. Is there any way to change it just for one model?

Answer (score 1):

Not looking at your code is hard to give an exact answer but you can override any admin template by extending it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template

Below is an example to extend change_form similarly you can do for any admin form - just find where this add button is and extend it.

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block object-tools-items %}
CUSTOM_CODE    
{% endblock %}
```

There might be possibility to do via python code as well but need to see code for it